# Undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression in Microsoft Access

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

why my query "CONVERT" in Microsoft Access odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression.

**This is my query**

[image]

```
<?php

// setup database for your microsoft Access
// you can setup password in you microsoft Access

// this is a variable for your connection in odbc
// "zkConnection" is your ODBC Data Source Administrator
$conn = odbc_connect("zkConnection", "", "");

// create condition for testing conecction
if ($conn) {
    // echo "<br>Connection Established</br>";
} else {
    echo "Koneksi Gagal";
}

$from_date = $_REQUEST['from_date'];
$to_date = $_REQUEST['to_date'];

$query = "INSERT INTO CalculateData(USERID, Name, lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, datein, timein, dateout, timeout)
          SELECT USERID, Name, lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, CONVERT(date, CHECKTIME) AS datein, MIN(CHECKTIME) AS timein, CONVERT(date, CHECKTIME) AS dateout, MAX(CHECKTIME) AS timeout
          FROM TransactionLog
          WHERE CHECKTIME BETWEEN #$from_date# AND #$to_date#
          GROUP BY USERID, Name, lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, CONVERT(date, CHECKTIME)";

$letsgo = odbc_exec($conn, $query);

if ($letsgo === false)
{
    die(print_r( odbc_error(), true));
}

header("location: index.php");

?>
```

is any idea for this solution ??

Comment: seems there is no `CONVERT` function, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-functions-by-category-b8b136c3-2716-4d39-94a2-658ce330ed83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as `CONVERT` in Access SQL.

Instead, each conversion has a separate function, e.g. `CDate`, `CInt`, `CStr`, etc.

Swap `CONVERT(date,`  with `CDate(`. Note that date conversions in Access assume either yyyy-mm-dd or mm/dd/yyyy.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions for the full list of conversion functions.